# Script_sig for coinbase transaction afbff1130b6fcbdceebbadfc48a842af1f03ee08a79e042b37fc467518b49a0f

Tags: script, network, coinbase-transaction, input-script

I am currently developing a blockchain parser in Python, and it has been crashing in the file blk00006.dat for the coinbase transaction with the hash `afbff1130b6fcbdceebbadfc48a842af1f03ee08a79e042b37fc467518b49a0f` in the block `0000000000000a46714e1b03e5e0693e9ecaa3ec1853f1cdf34e9ca52e13f1ff`. The reason it was crashing is because it has an `OP_PUSHDATA2` in the script signature with a value of 28265. However, there are only 21 bytes left to read according to the size of the script.

I fixed my code to avoid crashing in this script, but I am still curious about how this script_signature got accepted by the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts are not *parsed*. From the protocol perspective they are byte arrays, and their contents is irrelevant for transaction deserialization.

Scripts are *executed* however, at the time they participate in spending. For outputs, that is when they are (attempted to be) spent. For non-coinbase inputs, that is immediately. Coinbases never participate in spending, so for almost(*) all purposes, they are just byte arrays.

(*) There are two partial exceptions to this. BIP34 requires the coinbase to start with a push of the block height. The 80000 vsigops limit also counts CHECKSIG operations in coinbases (treating them as scripts, but it stops counting at the first invalid opcode).

Comment: Awesome1 Thanks for the great explanation.